# Is this line correct?

Tags: grammar

Is it corrct if I use this line-

"I have not that sort of brain."

I have a little bit confusion about that.

Comment: As a sentence it is grammatically sound. But I am reluctant to recommend it without a bit more context as to how you want to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is grammatical, but problematic. "I have not X" sounds formal and possibly archaic, whereas "that sort of brain" sounds informal and modern, which leads me to believe it would be difficult to find an appropriate context.

How about:

- *"I have not got that sort of brain"*

or

- *"I don't have that sort of brain"*